# Filtering on a highly nested STRUCT in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I have a row with a basic string array and a want to filter by an element in the array, I can use the pattern as below:

```
with members as (
  select 'Bob' AS name, ['Running', 'Piano'] AS hobbies union all
  select 'Derek', ['Cooking']
) select name, hobbies from members, unnest(hobbies) as hobby where hobby = 'Piano'
```

How would I do the same thing with a struct within the top-level array, for example to get all items with `members.hobbies = 'Guitar'` in the below?

```
-- members.hobbies = 'Guitar'

with teams as (
  select 'Cubs' AS name, [STRUCT<name STRING, hobbies ARRAY<STRING>>('Derek', ['Guitar', 'Cooking'])] as members union all
  select 'Jaguars', [('Bob', ['Running', 'Piano']), ('Sammy', ['Sailing'])]
) 
select t.name, members, y from teams t, unnest(members) as y;
```

My best attempt is the pretty hack-ish:

```
-- members.hobbies = 'Guitar'

with teams as (
  select 'Cubs' AS name, [STRUCT<name STRING, hobbies ARRAY<STRING>>('Derek', ['Guitar', 'Cooking'])] as members union all
  select 'Jaguars', [('Bob', ['Running', 'Piano']), ('Sammy', ['Sailing'])]
) , m1 as (select t.*, hobbies from teams as t, unnest(members) as m_unnest)

select m1.name, m1.members from m1, unnest(hobbies) as h where h='Guitar'
```

[image]

Comment: What specifically do you want the output to be? You're getting the correct row, are you asking to only get the single array element instead of the whole array? In which case just select `h` instead of the structure?

Comment: @MatBailie maybe something like a more generalized pattern if the object is something like `[{[{...` I just find it very difficult to figure out how to traverse STRUCTs that contain an array in it (or an array that contains a struct in it).

Comment: I'm asking what you want the results to be and you're replying with a comment about generalised search. I'm now even less clear about your specific question.

Comment: If you have an object you can use `table.column.object_element_name` to access a specific element. If you have an array, you need to unnest it to translate to multiple rows. If the array elements are then objects, you can use the same syntax to access its elements, if the array elements are arrays, you can unnest them again. Ad infinitum. It's a bit clunky, but sql wasn't designed for nested structures, that's a bespoke retrofit by Google.

Comment: `select * from teams where 'Guitar' IN UNNEST(members.hobbies);`  is not enough?

Comment: @Jaytiger In the second example it is an ARRAY of STRUCTs, each STRUCT containing a name (STRING) and a hobbies (another ARRAY, of STRINGs). So, needs two levels of unnesting.

Comment: @MatBailie, I agree what you're saying and I think your explanation is correct and is a formal approach. but above query will work and return what PO wants.  I can't explain why this syntax works. maybe undocumented feature ?  I saw this kind of syntax works several times and looking for reasonable explanation but failed.

Comment: @Jaytiger Until I see that for myself (and I'll test tomorrow, it's 3am here), I don't believe that works on an ARRAY<STRUCT<ARRAY<STRING>>>, the syntax only makes sense for STRUCT<ARRAY<STRING>>. As written in the OP, there is no `teams.members.hobbies`, you'd need to unnest `teams.members` before you can access `hobbies` (so that you can then unnest `hobbies`).

Comment: @MatBailie the output is exactly what I have in the question screenshot, I'm just asking about a more general way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about tidying up your query, I would use...

```
WITH
  teams AS
(
  SELECT
    'Cubs' AS name, [STRUCT<name STRING, hobbies ARRAY<STRING>>('Derek', ['Guitar', 'Cooking'])] as members

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    'Jaguars', [('Bob', ['Running', 'Piano']), ('Sammy', ['Sailing'])]
)
SELECT
  t.name,       -- STRING
  t.members,    -- ARRAY of STRUCTS
  m,            -- STRUCT; each element of the ARRAY t.members
  m.name,       -- STRING; the name item from the STRUCT m
  m.hobbies,    -- ARRAY;  the hobbies item from the STRUCT m
  h             -- STRING; each element from the ARRAY m.hobbies
FROM
  teams   AS t
CROSS JOIN
  unnest(t.members) AS m
CROSS JOIN
  unnest(m.hobbies) AS h
WHERE
  h = 'Guitar'
```

The SELECT clause then includes everything at every level of aggregation, and you can pick and choose which you actually want.

Comment: thanks for this, I didn't know you could chain `unnest`s, and so in your case doing `teams t, unnest(t.members) m, unnest(m.hobbiest) h` is a real big readability win -- thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Below query works but not recommended (use MatBailie's answer instead for your real dataset until having proper explanation)

```sql
with teams as (
  select 'Cubs' AS name, [STRUCT<name STRING, hobbies ARRAY<STRING>>('Derek', ['Guitar', 'Cooking'])] as members union all
  select 'Jaguars', [('Bob', ['Running', 'Piano']), ('Sammy', ['Sailing'])]
)
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE 'Guitar' IN UNNEST(members.hobbies);
```

**Query results**

[image]

As MatBailie explains, *ARRAY<STRUCT<ARRAY<STRING>>>* should be unnested twice but dot notation like **members.hobbies** seems to work at *IN UNNEST* clause.

Looking forward for someone to give me a reasonable explanation for this syntax.

Comment: Similar case - *MIN(d IN UNNEST(concat_dates.dates))* works also in the answer here.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392207/bigquery-array-concat-agg-over-a-window-function

Comment: Your link refers to arrays of arrays, not arrays of structs of arrays. Have you actually tested this?

Comment: @MatBailie, As you know, bigquery doesn't support arrays of arrays.  it's arrays of struct of arrays. *ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(dates)) OVER w0 AS concat_dates*. If you see I'm missing something, I'd appreciate if you let me know. thanks..

Comment: I did not know that, and only noticed the question, not the answer, I will do some testing later today.